# What's the jQuery equivalent of Prototype's positionedOffset

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

(to my knowledge) jQuery does not provide a native solution to find an element's offset to it's positioned parent. How can I get jQuery to give me the coordinates of an element's positioned offset

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's offsetParent() method, we can get the element that our current element is positioned from. Then we can compare the two offsets and extract the coordinates to get the information we are looking for. The below method will return an object with "top" and "left" properties.

```
// jQuery equivalent to Prototype's positionedOffset
(function($) {
    $.fn.positionedOffset = function() {
        // get viewport offset for our main element
        var coords = $(this).offset();

        // get parent and parent viewport offset 
        var parent = $(this).offsetParent();
        var parentCoords = $(parent).offset();

        // do some math to calculate relative offset
        var diff_left = coords.left - parentCoords.left;
        var diff_top = coords.top - parentCoords.top;

        // return values
        var offsetCoords = {
            left: diff_left,
            top: diff_top
        }

        return offsetCoords;
    };
})(jQuery);
```